# Magento Observer is not firing

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to fire an observer whenever a product is updated in the admin cp. To log the updates.

*Config.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mod_Products>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Mod_Products>
    </modules>

    <models>
        <Mod_Products>
            <class>Mod_Products_Model</class>
        </Mod_Products>
    </models>

    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_after>
            <observers>
                <Mod_Products_stock>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Mod_Products_Model</class>
                    <method>logUpdate</method>
                </Mod_Products_stock>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_after>
    </events>
</config>
```

*Observer.php*

```
class Mod_Products_Model_Observer {
    public function logUpdate($observer) {
        $event = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName();

        Mage::log('Event Fired: ' . $event);
        Mage::log(json_encode($observer->getEvent()));
    }
}
```

There are no errors and no output in the log.

Comment: I'm assuming you have an `app/etc/modules/Mod_Products.xml` with active set to true and labeled with the correct codepool?

Comment: one trick is, if you're on a development server, put 'die' statements in various places. This has helped me confirm that either a file was not found/loaded by the autoloader, or a function was not being called (rather than the results simply not being what I thought they would be.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go through the files one by one.

**app/etc/modules/Mod_Products.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mod_Products>
            <!-- Change to Community codePool if in app/code/community -->
            <codePool>local</codePool> 
            <active>true</active>
        </Mod_Products>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Mod/Products/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mod_Products>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Mod_Products>
    </modules>

    <!-- Marking models as global sometimes helps -->
    <global>
        <models>
            <Mod_Products>
                <class>Mod_Products_Model</class>
            </Mod_Products>
        </models>
    </global>

    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_after>
            <observers>
                <mod_products_model_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Mod_Products_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>logUpdate</method>
                </mod_products_model_observer>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_after>
    </events>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Mod/Products/Model/Observer.php**

```
class Mod_Products_Model_Observer {
    public function logUpdate($observer) {
        $event = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName();

        Mage::log('Event Fired: ' . $event);
        Mage::log(json_encode($observer->getEvent()));
    }
}
```

Pay attention to file names and directories, and to the different xml handles in my updated config.xml. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: So I just ran through these, made them identical, checked names and I'm still not getting any results.

Comment: So why is this the accepted answer? How did you get your observer to get picked up by Magento?

Answer (score 2):

don't know why op accepted Jason's answer that didn't really solve it, but here's the correct answer for future seekers (I noticed it from Emi's comment on his own answer): **missing adminhtml tag!**

the config should look like this (assuming I didn't miss anything else):

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_after>
            <observers>
                <Mod_Products_stock>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Mod_Products_Model</class>
                    <method>logUpdate</method>
                </Mod_Products_stock>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_after>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The class inside your config must be the Observer class, so change to:

```
<class>Mod_Products_Model_Observer</class>
```

Comment: Still got nothing appearing in the log file

Comment: Impossible I've used this event like this `<adminhtml>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <obs_catalog_product_save_after>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Test_Obs_Model_Catalog_Product_Observer</class>
                        <method>saveAfter</method>
                    </obs_catalog_product_save_after>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
        </events>
</adminhtml>` so it should be working. I've tested it by saving a product in admin.

Comment: Yeah that was a typo, sorry. The observer is still not firing

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for those coming across this problem is that your Magento application may not have the proper permissions to write to the `app/var` folder. Especially if you are working with a UNIX/Linux based OS.

To solve this issue, simply locate your terminal to the root of your Magento application. Once you are there, use the following command to give your `var` folder the proper permissions:

`sudo chmod 777 -R var/`

Once I did this, my application was able to log and create other folders under the folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same situation and finally, found out the *Mage_Log* was not working. Try using something like *die("I'm here");* instead of *Mage::Log()* for tracking and see whether it comes across your class or not. If so, try turning on *Mage_Log* via *Configuration: Developer: Log Setting (Enabled=Yes)*.
Also, check if *Mage_Log* is enabled at the *Configuration: Advanced*.

Answer (score 0):

Once i got the same issue and i resolved that just by Flushing the system cache,so you can also try to flush the cache to refresh its configurations.

Answer (score -1):

check if your module exist in `"disable module output"` and enabled
`System -> configuration -> advenced ->` disable module output.
And check your system log file